# c# stop program from sending events to the event viewer

Tags: c#

ive made a simple program which when u click a button, accesses your gps coordinates. This also alerts the user by sending a message to the event viewer which i dont want. I did abit of research and tried to do it in the following way but its not working for me.

```
    string Longitude;
    string Latitude;

    [ServiceProcessDescriptionAttribute("SBAutoLog")]

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AutoLog = false; //disables sending events to the event viewer
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //gets users gps
    {
        GeoCoordinateWatcher GEOWatcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(750);
        GEOWatcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
        GeoCoordinate Coordinates = GEOWatcher.Position.Location;

        if (Coordinates.IsUnknown != true)
        {
            Latitude = Coordinates.Latitude.ToString();
            Longitude = Coordinates.Longitude.ToString();
            GEOWatcher.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            GEOWatcher.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public static bool AutoLog { get; set; }
```

any help is appriciated, thanks

Comment: Where is the AutoLog property used?

Comment: i think it refers to the public static bool Autolog at the bottom. im not that familer with it

Comment: Didn't you wrote that code?

Comment: no i found someone trying to do the same thing and copied the answer he got, its only 3 lines of code but doesnt work for me

Comment: Is this for Windows Phone?

Comment: no its just a windows application

Comment: And what is not working exactly?  Getting the coordinate or preventing the event log?

Comment: preventing the event log